# How to use instance methods as jobs for APscheduler AND in conjunction with persistent datastore [unbound method error]

Tags: python, mongodb, methods, apscheduler, unbound

[Note: using Python 2.7 and jupyter notebook environment]

I would like to be able to schedule instance methods as jobs using APscheduler and store these jobs in a persistent DB [in this case, mongodb].

When trying to do so however, I hit the following error: `unbound method use_variable() must be called with Job instance as first argument (got NoneType instance instead)`

Previous to this i've successfully:
(a) scheduling instance methods as jobs
(b) storing jobs in mongodb

However, I can't get these two to work in conjunction.

**What works:**

A basic example of (a) scheduling instance methods as jobs...

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

class Job:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.variable = config['variable']

    def use_variable(self):
        print(self.variable)

job=Job({'variable': 'test'})
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job.use_variable, trigger='interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
```

Runs as expected, printing 'test' every 5 seconds.

**What breaks:**

However, as soon as I add a jobstore...

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore

class Job:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.variable = config['variable']

    def use_variable(self):
        print(self.variable)

job=Job({'variable': 'test'})

jobstores = {'default': MongoDBJobStore(
    database='apscheduler', collection='jobs')}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)
scheduler.add_job(job.use_variable, trigger='interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
```

The job successfully runs the first time, but on all subsequent calls errors due to 'unbound method'. I'd guess that the job instance is not being retrieved from the jobstore, so that no 'self' is passed to the use_variable method...

**From the docs...**

From the docs: `In case of a bound method, passing the unbound version (YourClass.method_name) as the target function to add_job() with the class instance as the first argument (so it gets passed as the self argument)`

As such, I tried:
`scheduler.add_job(Job.use_variable, args=[job] trigger='interval', seconds=5)`

No luck either.

**Current workaround**

I'm currently using the following workaround, however it's pretty hacky and I'd like to find a more elegant solution!

```
def proxy(job):
   job.use_variable()

scheduler.add_job(proxy, args=[job], trigger='interval', seconds=5)
```

**Update with blocking scheduler as suggested by Alex**

Minimal example code:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore

class Job:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.variable = config['variable']

    def use_variable(job):
        print(job.variable)


job = Job({'variable': 'test'})

jobstores = {'default': MongoDBJobStore(
    database='apscheduler', collection='jobs')}
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)

def my_listener(event):
    if (event.exception):
        print('Exception: {}'.format(event.exception))

scheduler.add_listener(my_listener)
scheduler.add_job(job.use_variable, trigger='interval',seconds=5)
// Also tried:
// scheduler.add_job(Job.use_variable, args=[job] trigger='interval',seconds=5)

scheduler.start()
```

Reproduces error. First call successfully prints 'test', but subsequent calls hit the unbound error [at least in a jupyter notebook environment]...

Comment: I tried the second example and it worked perfectly (after switching to BlockingScheduler of course). What was the error you encountered?

Comment: Hi Alex! Could you possibly explain / refer me to appropriate doc that explains why BlockingScheduler should be used?
I tried with blocking scheduler and hit the same error. I've added a minimal example to the question:

`Exception: unbound method use_variable() must be called with Job instance as first argument (got NoneType instance instead)`

Should also note: 
(a) using python 2.7
(b) in jupyter notebook environment for testing
(c) works on first call, but fails on second

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered a bug in APScheduler 3.6.0 which only manifests itself on Python 2.7. It tries to do the right thing regarding the scheduling of methods, but on py2.7 it does it wrong. I will fix this in the next release. In the meantime, you can keep using your workaround.

Comment: Look forward to it, thanks for looking into this Alex - much appreciated!